# Adjusting pixel values to new pixel sum

Tags: qgis, raster, pixel, values

I'm working with land use rasters in QGIS. For my application I have created rasters with pixels that have a fraction of 0-1 (for 0-100%) for a land use class. So for example in my settlement raster the pixel value is 0,2. The overlapping pixels from the other rasters have e.g. 0,4 for cropland and for 0,4 grassland.

I need to adjust the pixel sums of these rasters to bring them in line with statistical areas.

So I need something, that increases or lowers the values of the Pixels to a point where it is in line with the new sum value I provide, but at the same time avoids values to get smaller than 0 or larger than 1.

My thought was about something, that loops through the raster and increases/decreases the values to a point where the pixel sum is close to my wanted sum.

I have some basic programming skills, but I never really scripted something in Python before.
How can I solve this with a tool or the graphic modeler? Otherwise, I would also go into scripting.

Comment: Your question doesn't specifically state how much the increase or decrease will happen, but I infer that it will *not* be constant across the entire raster(s).  Is that correct?  If not constant across the entire raster, is there some pattern to the increase/decrease - perhaps by land use class or geographic area, or by some other variable?  Or does the increase/decrease have no pattern at all, totally inconsistent?

Comment: The increase/decrease should happen constantly at the Pixels that already have a value greater than 0. I derived land use patterns from different sources and created rasters with the fractions mentiont above.